# How to connect to remote ElasticSearch server installed on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: ubuntu, curl, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch (not installed as service) on AWS ubuntu 16. I am trying to connect it to my node application but I am getting connection refused.

**curl -XGET '52.x.x.x:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty**' also fetches me connection refused.

Things I have tried:
updating the network host in elasticsearch.yaml to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Check if `elasticsearch` is listening on port 9200.

Comment: yes, elasticsearch is listening on port 9200. When I put localhost instead of public ip of aws ec2 i.e 52.x.x.x, I get a proper response.

Comment: can you attach log files of elastic and complete error when you try curl command

Answer (score 4):

1st see if your firewall has an open 9200 port.

2nd in elasticsearch.yaml set network.host to 52.x.x.x and save it.

3th restart elasticsearch service: service elasticsearch restart

4th test it: curl -X GET 'http://52.x.x.x:9200'

Answer (score 3):

You should set the item network.host in conf/elasticsearch.yml file as:

```
network.host: 52.x.x.x
```

and restart the elasticsearch. The default value of network.host is localhost, so you can visit elasticsearch in localhost.